# c++ socket.io client cannot get message

Tags: c++, websocket, socket.io

I try to use c++ to connect coincap.io API. as library use socket.io-client-cpp. it's connected, but bot any message to from server. my code is:

```
    #include "socketio.h"

using namespace sio;

void OnMessage(sio::event &)
{
    std::cout << "get new msg" << std::endl;
}

std::mutex _lock;
std::condition_variable_any _cond;
bool connect_finish = false;

class connection_listener
{
    sio::client &handler;

public:

    connection_listener(sio::client& h) :
        handler(h)
    {
    }


    void on_connected()
    {
        _lock.lock();
        _cond.notify_all();
        connect_finish = true;
        _lock.unlock();

        std::cout << "sio is connect " << std::endl;

    }
    void on_close(client::close_reason const& reason)
    {
        std::cout << "sio closed " << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    void on_fail()
    {
        std::cout << "sio failed " << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
};

int participants = -1;

socket::ptr current_socket;

void bind_events()
{
    current_socket->on("trades", sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](std::string const& name, message::ptr const& data, bool isAck, message::list &ack_resp)
    {
        _lock.lock();
        std::cout << "get new msg" << std::endl;
        _lock.unlock();
    }));


}

socketio::socketio()
{

    std::cout << "socket.io test" << std::endl;

    sio::client h;
    connection_listener l(h);
    h.set_open_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_connected, &l));
    h.set_close_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_close, &l, std::placeholders::_1));
    h.set_fail_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_fail, &l));

    h.connect("http://coincap.io");


    current_socket = h.socket();



    bind_events();


}


socketio::~socketio()
{
}
```

After run i get in console:

```
socket.io test
Error: No active session
[2018-03-28 23:30:53] [connect] Successful connection
[2018-03-28 23:30:54] [connect] WebSocket Connection 104.17.37.95:80 v-2 "WebSocket++/0.7.0" /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&t=1522305053 101
sio is connect
```

but not get any "get new msg".

if I test socket.io in JS, like this:

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://coincap.io');
        socket.on('trades', function (tradeMsg) {
            console.log(tradeMsg);
            document.getElementById('trade').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tradeMsg)
        })
```

all work fine. Anyone have idea what I do wrong? Why it's not listener message? 
Thanks!

Comment: did you send something?

Comment: no. it not need to send. in example client get message after connection